# SVG Images Getting disappeared

Tags: image, svg

I've noticed this strange "bug" on my website. Sometimes some svgs aren't loaded correctly. Some images are loaded just fine, some svgs get loaded but not fully. (some parts aren't shown)

Here are examples:
Loaded fully, working fine - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBgyk.png

After closing page and opening it up for few times - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkHHR.png

Actual SVG image - https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1ln1a0diko0a12/parrothandshake.svg?dl=0

Comment: HTTP 404 on dropbox link

Answer (score 1):

You svg image: is a base64 converted png.

You can see it in the  tag attribute here: xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVB[...]

I would not recommend using base64 at all. Even more so in a image tag inside an svg image. (This is debatable and opinion based)

I would recomend using Inkscape to convert png images to svg. There is a build in function for converting in the editor. Its also free and a handy tool to have when working with svg images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it tomorrow.